# Change of navigation menu background color on scroll in WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

How can I set the navbar with no background color by default and to get the background color on scroll?

When scrolling down a div with a class `full-width-menu` should get a new bg color.

For a fixed location on top I use `navbar-fixed-top` from Bootstrap3.

I've tried almost every some tutorials that I came across but I didn't succeed.

I even tried with affix plugin from WordPress but no luck.

Here is [my code](http://viper-7.com/rI3hgW)

Comment: can you share real generated html source code without php?

Comment: To over-write a ! important you need another ! important #f8f8f8 ! important; out ways a follow up of Transparent unless you have Transparent ! important.

Comment: @jakob here is the jsfiddle with a generated html https://jsfiddle.net/pevoje/vtsmtatj/

Answer (score 0):

You can set this css for transparent as default:

```
.navbar-inverse{
  background-color:transparent;
  border-color:transparent;
}
```

And in jQuery just target that class `.navbar-inverse`

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/vtsmtatj/1/

Comment: sadly no wanted results :( any other suggestions?

Comment: well it works in demo as you can see... maybe some other code interrupts it.. can you set full source code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I can share over email skype if you want... Of Course if you are willing to help. My email is dndme@hmamail.com